# Is there a way to make excel Slicers "Stick" to a table in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for a way to have the slicer stick to the table in excel whether that be a simple function or VBA, any suggestions? For example; This is the table and the slicer next to each other [image]

However when you specify the table data for a day(say october 2nd) The table gets smaller but the slicer stays in the same place like this [image]

Is there a way to have the slicer snap on or stick to the table when it shrinks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the worksheet code module you can use something like this:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
    Dim pt As PivotTable, slc As Object
    Set pt = Me.PivotTables(1)        'or specific named pivot table
    Set slc = Me.Shapes("Call sign")  'for example
    
    With pt.TableRange1
        slc.Top = .Top   'move the slicer...
        slc.Left = .Columns(.Columns.Count).Offset(0, 1).Left
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, this looks like it can work, but I'm a bit of a novice in VBA, I'm declaring my pivot table then calling it right so I'd need to change pivotable in lines 2 and 3 to my pivot table name and it should work right? I did that but it says user defined type not defined. and highlights as the declaration. Did I change the wrong fields?

Comment: You don't call this code - it lives in the worksheet code module, and runs automatically whenever a pivot table is updated on that worksheet.

Comment: Okay thanks, I put it in but I kept getting a runtime error with the slc.top line, it keeps saying the specified value is out of range, I tried changing it to this


       'Dim wsHeight As Double
        wsHeight = Me.UsedRange.Height
        slc.Top = (wsHeight - slc.Height) / 2'



But same error, am I missing something ?

Comment: What's the value of `pt.TableRange1.Top` when you get the error?

Comment: I don't believe there's a specific value set, it's just set to take the top edge of the table data range

Comment: Add `Debug.Print .Top, .Left` above the line `slc.Top = .Top`  What values do you get in the VB editor Immediate window ? (Ctrl+G to show if it's not already visible)

Comment: I added the line and in the window I got 165 0

Comment: Then I don't know why you'd get that error...  Are you able to share your workbook (or a "cleaned" version which shows the same problem)?  Either here or via email.

Comment: Whilst creating a cleaned version for you I actually tested it out and it worked, Let me take a closer look at it with all the data. Thanks for all the help! I don't suppose you have anything out there I can read up on to learn some more? Really interested. Send me a message?

Comment: I can't think of anything specific to look at as a reference - anything I know is mostly just bits and pieces from spending far too much time here on SO...